# Check what URL was returned using requests library

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

My problem is pretty simple.

If I visit the following url:
https://pixabay.com/en/editors_choice/?media_type=photo&pagi=999

The url I actually end up in is: https://pixabay.com/en/editors_choice/?media_type=photo&pagi=

Using the following code, how do I check what URL I ended up in?

```
response = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `response.url`, see the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.url).